# Extracting numbers till a certain paragraph using multi condition Regex in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I am new to regex. I am  trying to extract the data from log files and each files has text like this:

```
crt - 00:00:00 up 200 days, 23:35, 0 users, load average: 0.04, 0.05, 0.02
Tasks: 300 total, 2 running, 298 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie
Cpu(s): 12.0%us, 2.5%sy, 0.0%ni, 89.2%id, 0.0%hi, 0.1%si, 0.0%st
Mem: 123456K total, 1234567k used, 989991k free, 11156793k buffers
Swap: 456K total, 30897564k used, 785431k free, 23445897k cached

PID User Pr NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
```

I am extracting only digit values till the word `cached`. For this i am buliding different patterns for each digit and then extracting values in a list using `finditer`. My code till now:

```
[x.group()for x in re.finditer(r"(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})|(\d+\.\d+?)%id"), text]
```

This is a fragment of regex where i have to specify pattern for every digit like suffix and prefix string. Is there a more efficient way to take output?

```
desired_values=[00:00:00, 200, 23:35, 0, 0.04, 0.05, 0.02 , 
               300, 2, 298, 0, 0, 
               12.0, 2.5, 0.0, 89.2, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 
               123456, 1234567, 989991, 11156793, 
               9234456, 30897564, 785431, 23445897]

These values then i insert in database, that's why they should be in list.
```

Comment: `re.findall(r'(?<!\d)(?:\d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?|\d*\.?\d+)(?!\d)', text)`? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cEQdxG/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can i specify it till the word 'cached'? As, there are digits after that which i don't need.

Comment: You may require the word to appear somewhere to the right of the match, `r'(?s)(?<!\d)(?:\d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?|\d*\.?\d+)(?!\d)(?=.*\bcached\b)'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that worked perfectly thanks a lot

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hey this is working good but what if i have the same text again. Like after the `PID` there are some numbers and then again same structured text from `crt` till `cached`. I want the values between "crt"  and "cached" everytime.

Comment: In that case, if you want, you may use PyPi regex module (install using `pip install regex`) and use `regex.findall(r'(?<!\d)(?<=\bcrt\b.*?)(?:\d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?|\d*\.?\d+)(?!\d)(?=.*\bcached\b)', text, regex.S)`. Or, first find the substring between the two words using `m = re.search(r'\bcrt\b.*?\bcached\b', text, re.S)`  and then run `re.findall(r'(?<!\d)(?:\d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?|\d*\.?\d+)(?!\d)', m.group())`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hey, i tried the code and it is finding all the values in text. Suppose if there are two paragraphs. 1) from 'crt' till 'cached'  and another one also from 'crt' till 'cached'. I want values between these two words. But it is giving me values also which are between these paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
r'(?s)(?<!\d)(?:\d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?|\d*\.?\d+)(?!\d)(?=.*\bcached\b)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/10Ilpc/2)

**Details**

- `(?<!\d)` - no digit immediately to the left is allowed
- `(?:\d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?|\d*\.?\d+)` - either of

  - `\d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?` - 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits and then an optional sequence of `:` and 2 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `\d*\.?\d+` - 0+ digits, an optional `.` and then 1+ digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit immediately to the right is allowed
- `(?=.*\bcached\b)` - there must be a word `cached` somewhere to the right of the current location.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/sUvwZe):

```
import re
text = r"""crt - 00:00:00 up 200 days, 23:35, 0 users, load average: 0.04, 0.05, 0.02
Tasks: 300 total, 2 running, 298 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie
Cpu(s): 12.0%us, 2.5%sy, 0.0%ni, 89.2%id, 0.0%hi, 0.1%si, 0.0%st
Mem: 123456K total, 1234567k used, 989991k free, 11156793k buffers
Swap: 456K total, 30897564k used, 785431k free, 23445897k cached
 
PID User Pr NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND"""
print( re.findall(r'(?<!\d)(?:\d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?|\d*\.?\d+)(?!\d)(?=.*\bcached\b)', text, re.S) )
```

Output:

```
['00:00:00', '200', '23:35', '0', '0.04', '0.05', '0.02', '300', '2', '298', '0', '0', '12.0', '2.5', '0.0', '89.2', '0.0', '0.1', '0.0', '123456', '1234567', '989991', '11156793', '456', '30897564', '785431', '23445897']
```